# Best way to populate class properties with external data

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic (and hopefully most efficient) way of populating object's properties with data coming from other objects, say Pandas dataframes? Currently I'm passing the data as argument in the constructor:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, row, mapping):
    self._foo = row["foo"]
    self._bar = self.mapping_method(row["bar"], mapping)
  
  def mapping_method(self, value, mapping):
    return mapping.loc[value, "some_column"]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  i = Item(row, mapping)
```

But I have the feeling passing a whole dataframe around and around isn't the best way to do it. Can this be improved somehow?

Comment: "passing a whole dataframe around and around isn't the best way to do it": I think it's far from that bad. You're effectively passing a pointer to the dataframe, not copying it every time you pass it.

Comment: What 9769953 said, but (not that it makes a difference) you're effectively passing a pointer to the _row_ that you want to use. Your approach seems fine to me.

Comment: Some structure of row and mapping variables could be useful. Does mapping hold the names of properties that need to be set, or what?

Comment: Do note that `self._foo` directly refers to `df['foo']`. If you alter `i._foo[3] = 11`, for example, you'll find `df.loc[3, 'foo']` is also 11 (depending on whether 3 is a valid index of course).

Comment: Ah, I missed the `iterrows` part (why not `df.iterrows()` though?). That means my above comment doesn't really apply, since the value isn't a series/column anymore. But if it were, the above would be the case (i.e., if you did `i = Item(df, mapping)` or the like).

Comment: IMO, you need to know if the argument you are passing is mutable or immutable. If it is mutable, it's your responsibility to pass a copy of the value if you don't want the receiver to mutate it (which means it's also your responsibility to know if the receiver *might* mutate it or not).

Comment: @9769953 Sorry, it was a typo. I'm actually calling df.iterrows()

Comment: @Gnudiff I pass an English label as index and get back a dict with multilanguage label-value pairs that get assigned to a property

Answer (score 1):

The basic question is where the list of properties to use are coming from.

Are properties preset by object or does object want to get all columns of dataframe row as properties?

In the second case, something like this:

```
class Item:
  MAPPED_COLUMNS={'bar':'some column'}
  def __init__(self, row, mapping):
    self.map_to_properties(row, mapping)
  
  def map_to_properties(self, row, mapping):
    for col in dict(row):
        if col in Item.MAPPED_COLUMNS:
            setattr(self,col,mapping.loc[ col, Item.MAPPED_COLUMNS[col] ])
        else:
            setattr(self,col,row[col])
```

Comment: the thing here is that I want all columns, but some need to undergo further manipulation with the aid of a second dataframe

Comment: @MartimPassos Then you just make a mapping of column names as part of class. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give your class two public constructors. The basic way of constructing the class would be to call it directly with data items you intend to store. Then you'd add a `classmethod` that would translate data from a specific kind of source (like a row of a dataframe) and build an instance using that data.

This design would allow you to use the same class even if you later need to process data that comes to you in a completely different format (like a database entry, or a json response from a web query). You'd just add a new classmethod to interpret the new data format and use the result to create your objects. The core of the class doesn't care what form the data came in with, it just needs to *use* that data.

For your example class, I might do:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, foo, bar):
    self._foo = foo
    self._bar = bar

  @classmethod
  def from_df_row(cls, row, mapping):
    return cls(row["foo"], mapping.loc[row["bar"], "some_column"])

for index, row in iterrows(df):
  i = Item.from_df_row(row, mapping)
```

I chose to fold the `mapping_method` into the `from_df_row` classmethod, but it may make sense to keep it as part of `__init__` if it's something fundamental to the meaning of `_foo` and `_bar` and the class (rather than something specific to the data source you're currently using).

Comment: How would you adapt this to 20+ properties? The example is an overly simplified version of my actual code